# Focus on row in table after move stayed in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple table where I can move up and move down rows. When I mouseover on the row the row focused:

```
jQuery('.tableItem').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        jQuery(this).css("background-color", "#f8f8f8");
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        jQuery(this).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
    }
});
```

When I mouseover on the row and click move up or down I have problem, because the focus stayed on two rows. Actual row and moved row. This problem occurs only in Firefox and IE. In Chrome and Opera all works good. Focus stayed only row on actual mouseover.

Example move up function, but I think this not a problem:

```
moveUp = function (actionLink) {
    var tableItem= jQuery(actionLink).parents(".table-item");
    var previoustableItem = jQuery(tableItem).prev();

    if (jQuery(previoustableItem ).attr("class") == "table-item") {
        jQuery(tableItem).insertBefore(previoustableItem );
    }
}
```

How to solved it? Why this work good only in Chrome and Opera?

Comment: I guess you probably wouldn’t have this problem in the first place, had you used a simple CSS rule using `:hover` to change the background, instead of using JavaScript/jQuery …